# How to print multiline variables in side-by-side columns in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have two variables which contain multi-line information and I want to column them.

`varA` returns

```
Aug 01
Aug 04
Aug 16
Aug 26
```

and `varB` returns

```
04:25
07:28
03:39
10:06
```

if i print both variables, it returns

```
Aug01
Aug04
Aug16
Aug26
04:25
07:28
03:39
10:06
```

What I want to do is the following:

```
Aug01 04:25
Aug04 07:28
Aug16 03:39
Aug26 10:06
```

I'm new to using Linux and I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: Please include the bash code you used in your attempt to print the two variable. It is so that we can see what you have done wrong in your attempt.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Meet `paste`, part of the preinstalled [GNU core utilities](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/coreutils):

```
$ paste <(printf %s "$varA") <(printf %s "$varB")
Aug 01  04:25
Aug 04  07:28
Aug 16  03:39
Aug 26  10:06
```

`paste` takes files and not variables as input, so I used [`bash` Process Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) and just printed the variable content with `printf`. The default delimiter between columns is `TAB`, you can change that with the `-d` option, e.g. `paste -d" "` for a single space character. To learn more about `paste` have a look at the [online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/paste-invocation.html#paste-invocation) or run `info '(coreutils) paste invocation'`.

Comment: @BNairb If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to simply display the text variables side by side, @dessert has the most simple (best?) solution using `print`. However if you want to be able to manipulate each piece individually, you could easily convert the vars to arrays instead, and loop through that.

```
#!/bin/bash

# declare the multi-line variables
var1="1
2
3
4"
var2="a
b
c
d"

# backup internal field separator to be safe
IFSave=$IFS

# set IFS to newline so vars will use newline to split into array
IFS=$'\n'

# split variables into array
foo=($var1)
bar=($var2)

#restore IFS to original value to be safe
IFS=$IFSave

# loop array foo, and cross reference key in array bar
for i in "${!foo[@]}"; do 
  printf "${foo[$i]} : ${bar[$i]}\n"
done

# you can allso now print single corresponding lines:
line=3

let id=$line-1 # arrays start at 0, so need to remove one

printf "\nPrinting line number $line\n"
printf "${foo[$id]} : ${bar[$id]}\n"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the POSIX tool `pr`:

```
varA='Aug 01
Aug 04
Aug 16
Aug 26'
varB='04:25
07:28
03:39
10:06'
pr -2 -t <<eof
$varA
$varB
eof
```

Result:

```
Aug 01                              04:25
Aug 04                              07:28
Aug 16                              03:39
Aug 26                              10:06
```

Or for single tab:

```
pr -2 -t -s
```

Or for single space:

```
pr -2 -t -s' '
```

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pr.html

Or with `column` from the `util-linux` package:

```
column -c 20 <<eof
$varA
$varB
eof
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to avoid external utilities and do it natively in the shell, you could use `read` with separate file descriptors / here strings for each variable:

```
while IFS= read -r -u3 a && read -r -u4 b; do 
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$a" "$b"
done 3<<<"$varA" 4<<<"$varB"
Aug 01  04:25
Aug 04  07:28
Aug 16  03:39
Aug 26  10:06
```

Although it's often considered bad practice to use the shell for text processing, it might be excused in the case that you already have the data in shell variables.